# Можно ли вызывать store.getState() внутри асионхронных экшинов?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk, redux-middleware

Можно ли вызывать `store.getState()` внутри асионхронных экшинов?  например у меня есть асинхронный экшин `submitForm`, который я диспатчу из контейнера так

```
onSubmit: (values) => dispatch(submitForm(values))
```

Далее мой асинхронный экшин выглядит так

```
import store....

export const submitForm = values => async dispatch => {
    const inputType = store.getState().auth.inputType;
    const form = Object.keys(store.getState().form)[0];

    if (inputType === NUMBER && !isValid(form, values.message)) {
        return;
    }

    dispatch(change(form, 'message', ''));

    const handleConfirmNeeded = async result => {
        dispatch(authSubmitSuccess(result);
    };

    try {
        const response = await request('request', {
            phone_mobile: phoneValueReduced(values.message),
            source: store.getState().chat.activeCommand
        });


        dispatch(saveId(response.payload.id));

        return handleConfirmNeeded({
            confirmationType: result.confirmationData,
        });
    }     catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Вообще это нормальный асинхронный экшин? Или обычно запросы выносят куда-то в другое место?

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, запросы выносят в отдельное место. Ведь `action` и `reducer` должны быть чистыми функциями. Для того, чтобы выполнять сайд-эффекты(в том числе и запросы), создаётся `middleware`, который и берет на себя логику работы с "неочевидным" поведением.
Я знаю две основных библиотеки для такого: [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) и [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). Правда, это касается только ситуаций, когда данные, поступающие в компонент из `redux` приходят вам с сервера, и только если эти данные нужны вам в нескольких компонентах(например, юзер - типичный пример). Если данные не нужны вам во многих компонентах, или их изменения происходит только в одном месте - лучше храните их в локальном `state` компонента, т.к. `redux` - это не хранилище всех данных приложения, это хранилище данных, которые необходимо переиспользовать во многих местах.